# How Bessel's inequality ensures the convergence of a sequence in this proof

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, hilbert-spaces

I am reading the proof of the theorem $22$ on page $13$ of [this](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/gantumur/math580f18/laplacenotes.pdf) lecture notes. How Bessel's inequality was used to prove the convergence of the sequence $(P_mu)$ in $V$ where $V$ is a Hilbert space? I am asking this because there exists a sequence in a Hilbert space that converges weakly, but not converges strongly, then the Bessel's inequality does not seem sufficient to me to ensure that the sequence $(P_mu)$ converges in $V$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Anyway, the weak convergence of $(P_m u)$ to $v$ is enough to conclude that $u=v$.